# How to create a dictionary from a list of tuples without overwriting the first unique key value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

So I've got a list of tuples with a key and its corresponding value. I wanted to have it be displayed as a dictionary, so I wrote

```
def tup_to_dict (lst):
    return dict(lst)
```

Now if my lst was `[("A3", "green"), ("B5", "blue"), ("A3", "yellow")]`, my output would then be:

```
{'B5': 'blue', 'A3': 'yellow'}
```

How would I go about checking if a key was already assigned a value and not overwriting it if it was. So that my output would look like this:

```
{"A3": "green", "B5": "blue"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dict` uses the last value, you want to use the first value… swap ’em!

```
return dict(reversed(lst))
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks a bunch mate!

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
a = [("A3", "green"), ("B5", "blue"), ("A3", "yellow")]
b = dict((x,y) for x,y in reversed(a))
```